# dynamic table data retrieve - selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
<table id="tblListViewHeader" class="adminlist" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 1003px;">
<tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="divListView" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; overflow: auto; display: block;">
<table id="tblListView" class="adminlist" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
  <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'ActiveGradeTemplate', foreach: ActiveGrade }">
    <tr class="row0">
      <td data-bind="text:$index()+1" style="width: 5%;">1</td>
      <td data-bind="text: GradeName" style="width: 20%;">Vantage Point</td>
      <td align="right" data-bind="text: DisplayCreatedDate" style="width: 10%;">27 Mar 2013</td>
      <td align="right" data-bind="text: CreatedByUser" style="width: 10%;">Name</td>
      <td align="right" data-bind="text: DisplayModifiedDate" style="width: 10%;">27 Mar 2013</td>
      <td align="right" data-bind="text: ModifiedByUser" style="width: 10%;">Name</td>
      <td align="center" data-bind="text: Status" style="width: 5%;">Active</td>
      <td align="center" style="width: 10%;">
        <a id="lnkEdit_7" data-bind="click: $root.lnkEdit, attr:{'id':'lnkEdit_' + GradeID}" href="#">Edit</a>
        <span id="spanEdit_7" data-bind="attr:{'id':'spanEdit_' + GradeID}"></span>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row0">
     <td data-bind="text:$index()+1" style="width: 5%;">2</td>
     <td data-bind="text: GradeName" style="width: 20%;">test grade</td>
     <td align="right" data-bind="text: DisplayCreatedDate" style="width: 10%;">Yesterday</td>
     <td align="right" data-bind="text: CreatedByUser" style="width: 10%;">Name</td>
     <td align="right" data-bind="text: DisplayModifiedDate" style="width: 10%;">Yesterday</td>
     <td align="right" data-bind="text: ModifiedByUser" style="width: 10%;">Name</td>
     <td align="center" data-bind="text: Status" style="width: 5%;">Active</td>
     <td align="center" style="width: 10%;">
       <a id="lnkEdit_11" data-bind="click: $root.lnkEdit, attr:{'id':'lnkEdit_' + GradeID}" href="#">Edit</a>
      <span id="spanEdit_11" data-bind="attr:{'id':'spanEdit_' + GradeID}"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

How can I retrieve the `td` values for each and every row, this is for Dynamic generation. All the `tr` class names are the same: `<tr class="row0">`. How do I retreive the table data for the above formatted table?

Answer (score 15):

Try below code, this will print all cells data,

```
// Grab the table 
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("divListView")); 

// Now get all the TR elements from the table 
List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 

// And iterate over them, getting the cells 
for (WebElement row : allRows) { 
    List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 

    // Print the contents of each cell
    for (WebElement cell : cells) { 
        System.out.println(cell.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get data only from 2nd column of each row. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
  // Grab the table 
  WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("table-6")); 

  //Get number of rows in table 
  int numOfRow = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")).size(); 

  //Get number of columns In table.
  int numOfCol = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='table-6']/tbody/tr[1]/td")).size();


  //divided Xpath In three parts to pass Row_count and Col_count values.
  String first_part = "//*[@id='table-6']/tbody/tr[";
  String second_part = "]/td[";
  String third_part = "]";

  //take the second column values
  int j=2;

  //List to store the second column
  List<String> secondColumnList=new ArrayList<String>();

  //Loop through the rows and get the second column and put it in a list
  for (int i=1; i<=numOfRow; i++){

    //Prepared final xpath of specific cell as per values of i and j.
       String final_xpath = first_part+i+second_part+j+third_part;
       //Will retrieve value from located cell and print It.
       String test_name = driver.findElement(By.xpath(final_xpath)).getText();
       secondColumnList.add(test_name);  
       System.out.println(test_name);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Dynamic table data capturing:**
1.First of all Capture Table Head Count.
[`int tHeadCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr//th")).size();`]

2.Capture Table Row Count in which row your actual data exists.
  [-in my point of view i need data from first row it self, so i am hard coding it to zero.]
  If you want please add one for loop to existing code.

3.The actual solution starts from here.
Following is function call "Deposited By" is table heading text of corresponding table data.

```
String tableDataValue = managePackageTableData("Deposited By");

public String  managePackageTableData(String columnName) {

//In Following line i am capturing table contains how many headers.     
        int tHeadCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr//th")).size();

    int statusIndex = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<tHeadCount-1;i++)
    {
    String theadValue = driver.findElements(By.className("table")).get(0).findElements(By.tagName("tr")).get(0).findElements(By.tagName("th")).get(i).getText();


    if(theadValue.equalsIgnoreCase(columnName))
    {
        statusIndex = i;
        break;
    }
    }       
    String tableData = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tbody")).get(0).findElements(By.tagName("tr")).get(0).findElements(By.tagName("td")).get(statusIndex).getText();

    return tableData;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options, but there's mine.
You catch all tds into a list.

```
List<WebElement> tdlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table[id='divListView'] tr td"));
```

and if you want to have the value, you can use a loop.

```
for(WebElement el: tdlist)  {
    Systeme.out.println(el.getText());   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this 
Most common Challenge Automation tester face during iterating through Table and list. they often want to find some value from the table cell or list and want to perform action on the same value or find corresponding other element in the same block and perform action on it.

http://qeworks.com/iterate-table-lists-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 0):

I have done this code using `TestComplete` and have replicated it now with Selenium C#, I have learnt this hard way but will work for any table control and you don't have to hardcode any `xpath` elements in it. Also if you have a nested table control within a `td` like for example where you have a nested table structure where your data is interpreted like below(happens in complex tables when you use developer express grids or angular grid controls).This case if you see the `td` tag again has a nested table structure which again has duplicate data. You can either capture such data or leave it depending on the case using the code which I am giving below.

Html

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Account #
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Account #
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
   </td>
   <td>Name 
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Name
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
   </td>
</tr>   
<tr>
   <td>1234 
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
              1234            
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
   </td>
    <td>Bharat
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td> 
           Bharat               
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Code

```
  public List<TableDataCollection> StoreHtmlTableToList(IWebElement tblObj)
        {
            DataTable dataTbl = new DataTable();
            int rowIndex = 1;

            try
            {               
                _tblDataCollection = new List<TableDataCollection>();

                var tblRows = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)DriverContext.Driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].rows; ", tblObj);

                if (tblRows != null)
                {
                    //Iterate through each row of the table
                    foreach (IWebElement tr in (IEnumerable)tblRows)
                    {                        
                        int colIndx = 1;
                        // Iterate through each cell of the table row
                        var tblCols = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)DriverContext.Driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].cells; ", tr);
                        foreach (IWebElement td in (IEnumerable)tblCols)
                        {

                            //loop through any child or nested table structures if you want using the same approach

                            //Write Table to List : This part is not done yet

                            //Print the values
                            Console.WriteLine("Row[" + rowIndex.ToString() + "] Col[" + colIndx.ToString() + "] : " + td.Text);
                            colIndx++;
                        }
                        rowIndex++;
                    }

                }


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return _tblDataCollection;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@ Ripon Al Wasim

The below code will helps you to find values column by column

```
WebElement customtable = t.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.custom-table"));
List<WebElement> r = customtable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for (WebElement row : r) {
            List<WebElement> d = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));            
            for(int i = 0; i<d.size(); i++) {
                if(i==0) {
                    WebElement x =d.get(i);
                    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) t.driver;
                    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", x);
                    System.out.println(i+"."+d.get(i).getText()+"\n");                  
                    if(d.get(i).getText().contains(searchtext)) {                       
                        System.out.println(i+".yes\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("No\n");
                    }

                }
            }           
}
```

its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

//tbody/tr

this will give you the total no of row-

//tbody/tr/td

this will give you all the cell for the above rows and you can iterate it based on your requiredment.

Answer (score 0):

## Below are different approach we can follow to handle dynamic data in application [Its not for dynamic elements];

1. Using excel approach;

   a.   Get the web-element of the field

   b.   Get its text .

   c.   Store the data in the excel and validate with actual result pattern.

Note  : There are multiple data validation options in excel like compare columns, get duplicate etc..

2. Using collection;

   a.    Get the web-element of the field.

   b.    Get its data inside the collection [List, set, map etc]

   c.    Write the java code to compare the pattern of the application data.

   ```
       i.  Pattern can be data type, data length, data range ,Decimal places of amount field or other ,currency type, date and time pattern etc.

       ii. You can write the java conditions to verify the values of charts/graphs/dashboard if you are using in your application.
   ```

   d.  Compare the actual data pattern[from the collection] and the expected data pattern[From the java code]
3. Use JDBC API to handle it through the database where you can check the actual data by using different commands.